# how to redirect all /?[xyz] to 404

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-404

I've tried a number of things... I know I'm missing something.  Help!!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^\? - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule` does not work directly on query strings, you have to use `RewriteCond` to access them (or tricks on internal rewrites, but that's not necessary here).

Try

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [R=404,L]
```

Any request to the root path with a query will end in a 404 response.